# Jquery image overlay gallery parameter issue

Tags: jquery, css, slide

I'm using [the mosaic sliding boxes and captions plugin](http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/1.0/). It's pretty smooth but I'd love to fix two problems, visible on this jfiddle. Some CSS/jQuery wiz here will know:

http://jsfiddle.net/9ZPrf/2

1) The overlay box doesn't cover the bottom of the image. I've fiddled with many of the obvious parameters in the CSS and jQuery. This problem has emerged because I add the hover_y parameter in my inline script. That is designed to raise the overlay higher so more text becomes visible.

2) The opacity only changes when you hover on the overlay, but it would be good if it changed wherever you are over the image, which is what the slide responds to.

I've already tried many of the obvious parameters, I'm hoping someone here can help.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to use a plugin for such a simple thing?

Comment: As simple as what? Creating an image overlay which slides up on hover? It's not that simple, and having a library do it is quite common practice when you're building a complex site. Perhaps one day I'll be able to rattle these tricks off in a jiffy. Pray for me til then Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I've fixed it for you http://jsfiddle.net/9ZPrf/4/

I'd like to give you some explanations, but this is general HTML/CSS, so it is difficult to do it briefly. Good luck learning!

Comment: Hi thanks for trying, but that cuts off much of the text. I added in the hover_y parameter (which you appear to have removed) precisely to reveal more text beneath. This doesn't fix it. Any other ideas?